# Search engine on a CD

Tags: excel, csv, actionscript, search-engine

My new project consists in setting a CD containing a structured data sheet (CSV, XML or Excel) and a search engine. The idea is to allow the user (even not connected) to make searches live on the CD. There will also be an up-to-date version of the data on internet so if the user is connected, the application will priority load the online data.
I was thinking at using ActionScript and XML.

My questions are:

1. Is ActionScript + XML a good choice?
2. Is it possible to think at PHP + XML (so how to embed PHP on a CD without a server?)

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely to search through an index, instead of the actual XML files, which will take a looooong time. Additionally, the index should be a data structure loaded into memory, to further improve the speed of the search.

Perhaps you will find this article useful: http://www.servebox.org/actionscript-foundry/actionscript-foundry-documentation/full-text-search-tree/

In order to use php without a webserver, you can use it from a command line interface. This is the link to some documentation on this matter: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.
I have been ill for some days and just recovered. Will track your link and revert back.

Thank you.

Comment: Glad you're feeling better. Good luck!